# Switching between views in Ionic2 is too slow

Tags: performance, angular, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic application, I have built 50% of the project, and at first I used the [sidemenu](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-sidemenu) template that is auto generated with `ionic start MyProject sidemenu`, and then I added my own pages and components after that.

In the browser view the app was great, then I deployed my application to an android device, with the deployment being successfully When I start the application I felt that the application was slow, but when I switch to a some view, it took 5-10 seconds to open the new page.

I watched the traffic between the server side and the application, and observed that the application is not switching to the new page until the request is back and the view is rendered!

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to your views first and then using the ionViewWillEnter() or another built in ionic API for the application lifecycle.

ionViewWillEnter will pull the data everytime the view loads, where

ionViewDidLoad will pull the page on first load only.

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SplashPage');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not state which version of ionic you are using but in ionic 3 if you create your pages with the terminal using

```
 ionic g page MyPage
```

It will automatically create the page as a module. This allows for lazy loading. You can read more on it [here](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/) form ionic's official blog post.

Its hard to say exactly why the view is only loading after it hits the server as you have not added your navigational code. There could be a code block that waits for a server response before pushing to the next page.

If your view is depended on received data from the server then your request should be in a `new Promise` allowing you to add conditionals for before and/or after the data has been touched.